# Mudando span do botão por meio de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho um botão que no clique do mesmo direciona a uma requisição em ajax para um arquivo externo que adiciona um produto, porém isso não importa muito nesse caso. Eu queria manipular o que está escrito no `span` do botão. Toda vez que o usuário clicasse em comprar, o mesmo mudaria para remover. E, aconteceria o inverso também, toda vez que o usuário clicasse no botão remover, o `span` desse botão mudaria para comprar. O que eu consegui fazer foi que o `span` do botão clicado mudasse para remover, porém o inverso ainda não.

**Código do botão:**

```
 <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
```

**Código da requisição Ajax:**

```js
function addCartao(product_id) {
  $j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "teste.php",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(retorno) {
      $j('button[name=cartaoMensagem' + product_id + ']').html('Remover'); //Código que consegui fazer

    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    error: function(x, y, z) {
      alert("error");
      alert(x);
      alert(y);
      alert(z);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Vc quer alterar só o texto? E a função do botão?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar o `html` todo o conteúdo é substituído, então você deve recolocar os `span´s`.

```
success: function(retorno) {
      var button = $j('button[name=cartaoMensagem' + product_id + ']');

      if($j(button).text() == '<span><span>Comprar</span></span>'){
              $j(button).html('<span><span>Remover</span></span>');
      }else{
              $j(button).html('<span><span>Comprar</span></span>');
      }


    },
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: Estou precisando de mais uma ajuda, no caso eu tenho mais de um botão de comprar e eu queria que toda vez que um botão comprar fosse clicado os outros fosse desabilitados e no clique do botão remover todos eram habilitados novamente. O código que eu fiz, coloco ele no `if` e os outros botões de comprar são desabilitados.Porém quando clico no botão remover, eu não consigo fazer nada pois o botão continua desabilitado. Código que fiz: `$j('#cartao').find(':button').prop('disabled',true);`. Obs: #cartao é a div onde estão os botões.

Comment: Faça uma edição na pergunta com essa questão, pois aqui fica muito difícil de entender. A propósito, tu pode abrir uma nova pergunta também, qualquer coisa manda o link, quando possível responderei.

Comment: Tudo bem! Felipe aqui está o link da pergunta com isso que te falei no comentário e te agradeço por toda a ajuda prestada! link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233618/mudando-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bot%C3%A3o-via-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais elegante e curta de fazer isso:

```
success: function(retorno) {
  i = $j("#cartaoMensagem"+product_id);
  i.text() == "Comprar" ?
  ( i.html(i.html().replace("Comprar","Remover")), $j("#cartao b*texto grifado*utton").not(i).attr('disabled','disabled') )
  :
  ( i.html(i.html().replace("Remover","Comprar")), $j("#cartao button").removeAttr('disabled') );
},
```

Teste abaixo:

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function addCartao(product_id){
 i = $j("#cartaoMensagem"+product_id);
 i.text() == "Comprar" ? ( i.html(i.html().replace("Comprar","Remover")), $j("#cartao button").not(i).attr('disabled','disabled') ) : ( i.html(i.html().replace("Remover","Comprar")), $j("#cartao button").removeAttr('disabled') );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cartao">
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao(1)" id="cartaoMensagem1"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
<br>
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao(2)" id="cartaoMensagem2"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
<br>
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao(3)" id="cartaoMensagem3"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('span').on('click', function(){
   if($(this).attr('data-value') == 1){
      $(this).attr('data-value', 2)
      $(this).text('Remover')
   }else{
      $(this).attr('data-value', 1)
      $(this).text('Comprar')
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-value="1">Comprar</span>
```

Existem varias formas de se fazer isso, nesse caso trabalhei com `attr` e verifiquei o valor, troquei o texto e o valor dele a cada clique.