# Mudando função do botão via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Eu tenho alguns botões que no clique do mesmo direciona a uma requisição em ajax para um arquivo externo que adiciona um produto, porém isso não importa muito nesse caso. Eu manipulo esses botões, sendo que toda vez que o  botão com o `span` comprar, onde no clique do mesmo, o `span` é alterado para remover e quando o botão remover é clicado o `span` é alterado novamente para comprar. Eu preciso que toda vez que o botão comprar seja clicado, todos eles fiquem desabilitados para o clique menos o botão que estiver com o `span` remover, para que esse sendo clicado, o `span` seja alterado para comprar e que os outros botões já possam ser clicados novamente.

**Código do botão:**

```
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
```

**Código da requisição Ajax:**

```
function addCartao(product_id){
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "teste.php",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('button[name=cartaoMensagem' + product_id + ']');

                    if($j(button).text() == '<span><span>Comprar</span></span>'){
                        $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',true);
                        $j(button).html('<span>Remover</span>');
                    }else{
                        $j(button).html('<span>Comprar</span>');
                    }
                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                  }
              });
            }
```

**Obs: O código que eu fiz desabilita todos os botões que estão dentro da div cartão, que são esses que estão na pergunta, mas como eles estão desabilitados, no clique do botão que estiver com o `span` remover, o mesmo não faz nenhum tipo de ação.**

Comment: Na pergunta vc diz que tem 1 botão e depois que tem outros botões. Pode explicar melhor ou editar a pergunta?

Comment: Já editei corretamente agora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa passar para a função qual foi o botão clicado, para depois excluí-lo da lista de botões a serem desabilitados.

Segue abaixo um exemplo da lógica:

```js
function addCartao(product_id, botaoClicado){

  if($(botaoClicado).text() == 'Comprar'){
    $('#cartao').find(':button').not(botaoClicado).attr('disabled',true);
    $(botaoClicado).html('<span>Remover</span>');
  }else{
    $('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
    $(botaoClicado).html('<span>Comprar</span>');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cartao">
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('1', this)" name="cartaoMensagem1" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('2', this)" name="cartaoMensagem2" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
<button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('3', this)" name="cartaoMensagem3" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendi seu propósito na outra pergunta (inclusive coloquei a resposta completa lá).

Primeiro, atribua um `id` diferente para cada botão (o `id` deve ser único no documento). Você pode fazer assim:

```
id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
```

E com esse código no `:success` você terá o resultado esperado:

```
i = $j("#cartaoMensagem"+product_id);
i.text() == "Comprar" ?
( i.html(i.html().replace("Comprar","Remover")), $j("#cartao button").not(i).attr('disabled','disabled') )
:
( i.html(i.html().replace("Remover","Comprar")), $j("#cartao button").removeAttr('disabled') );
```

> Se for usar o código acima, remova o código abaixo do seu `:success`:

```
var button = $j('button[name=cartaoMensagem' + product_id + ']');

                    if($j(button).text() == '<span><span>Comprar</span></span>'){
                        $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',true);
                        $j(button).html('<span>Remover</span>');
                    }else{
                        $j(button).html('<span>Comprar</span>');
                    }
```

**Incluir uma função no IF/ELSE:**

No IF:

```
i.text() == "Comprar" ?
    ( i.html(i.html().replace("Comprar","Remover")), $j("#cartao button").not(i).attr('disabled','disabled'), funcao() )
    :
    ( i.html(i.html().replace("Remover","Comprar")), $j("#cartao button").removeAttr('disabled') );
```

No ELSE:

```
i.text() == "Comprar" ?
    ( i.html(i.html().replace("Comprar","Remover")), $j("#cartao button").not(i).attr('disabled','disabled') )
    :
    ( i.html(i.html().replace("Remover","Comprar")), $j("#cartao button").removeAttr('disabled'), funcao() );
```

Comment: Seu código deu certo e agradeço a ajuda, porém eu necessito de um if else para que dentro deles eu chame outras funções em jQuery.

Comment: Já tem. Depois do "?" é if e depois do ":" é else, dentro dos parênteses, separados por vírgula. Vou incluir no final da resposta como fazer isso.

Comment: Agradeço por toda a atenção e ajuda e novamente falando deu certo do modo que você me respondeu, porém para o caso que necessito a resposta que mais se adequou foi a que chequei como correta. Mas enfim, agradeço por toda a ajuda por sua parte.